# AlamofireImageのキャッシュ機能

Tags: swift, swift2

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let uiImage = self.view.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        uiImage.af_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")!)
    }

}
```

---

AlamofireImageを使用する際、上記のようにURLから画像を取得するだけで、
自動でキャッシュは生成されるものなのでしょうか。
TableViewなどで各セルに画像を表示したい場合（キャッシュを生成、利用したい）
上記の処理を含めた処理を実装することで実現できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlamofireImageは内部にキャッシュを持っていて、特に何も指定しなければURLごとに自動的にキャッシュが利用されます。ですので、同じURLに対してリクエストする限りは一度画像を取得していれば２度目以降はキャッシュから取得されます。